# Array in an annotation: how to organize a constant

Tags: java

I am using Java 11.0.8.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"ru.pcask.clients",
                                            "ru.pcask.activities",
                                            "ru.pcask.agent_profiles",
                                           })

@EntityScan(value={"ru.pcask.clients",
                   "ru.pcask.activities",
                   "ru.pcask.agent_profiles", })

@EnableJpaRepositories(value={"ru.pcask.clients",
                              "ru.pcask.activities",
                              "ru.pcask.agent_profiles",})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I organize some kind of a constant here in order not to hardcode these arrays every time?

They say it is possible via enum. But I failed to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by not hard coding it, to put values in an annotation only `public static final` fields, and by nature, these are hardcoded.

Comment: Why can't I organize a public static final var in a class? But this is not working.

Comment: You can't have an array as the fields of your annotation, as they require the values to be compile time constants (Strings, ints, floats ...)